# How to assign a session value in Global page and use it in all other forms in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get the URL from Global page to a .aspx.cs page.So i want to assign the url to a session and use that session in aspx.cs page.But it is showing error that session doesn't exist in this context.I tried by declaring a public variable and  using that public variable in cs page.But i am not able to do.Here is my code:
**1st method:**
   Global.asax.cs:

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                   Session["URL"] = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        }
```

aspx.cs:

```
string str = Session["URL"].ToString();
```

**2nd method**
Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
     public static string strurl = "";

           protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                       strurl  = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
            }
   }
```

aspx.cs:

```
string str = Global.strurl;
```

Pls help me out!!!

Comment: Do NOT use the second method: different users will see the url of the one that did the most recent request, not their own!

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand why you need something like that but as far as I know, session is initialized in the Session_Start event. Do something like

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["URL"] = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Yes i did the same.But i want all the urls in the application whenever a page is loaded.I am getting only the start page url if i do like this.SO i am trying to get it in cs page through Request.RawUrl.ToString()

Comment: I'm with Kemal. I don't understand why you need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit that like others I'm a little confused by the question but I'm thinking you may just want it as a kind of easy to use shortcut...

If you want something in the global page that you can use to get the current page url more easily than typing `Request.Url.ToString().ToLower()` repeatedly then you could do something like this:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public string currentUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage over session that it will always return the current page url and not just the most recent request. For example if you call a page (A) and that calls a graphic object through an aspx page (B) then you will only get one URL stored in session so you might get unexpected results when A is actually given B's url.

If you do actually want a shortcut on every page then what I'd actually suggest doing is something more like:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public string CurrentUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Then rather than your pages inheriting from the standard Page class you inherit them all from MyPage and you get CurrentUrl available in all pages without even having to reference an external entity.

If this isn't what you want then you may like to step back and describe the original problem that you are trying to solve rather than the problems with your solution. It may be that you are trying to get something working that is a bad idea to begin with. :)

Comment: k thank u for your suggestion. I got solution but not through global page.I am getting it in the .aspx.cs page itself through Request.RawUrl.ToString().

Comment: Ah. I had assumed that there was a reason why you weren't doing the obvious approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the PostAcquireRequestState event. In this event, session is already associated with the current request and you can access it. And is executed in every request!!

```
Private Sub Global_asax_PostAcquireRequestState(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PostAcquireRequestState
    Session.Add("item", "value")
End Sub
```